# Synonymous many to many model relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to achieve what you could call a "synonymous" relationship on a self referencing many to many field in Django.

Take this model for example (in reality I don't use real words, but category tags instead):

```
class Word(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    synonymous = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True,  related_name='synonymous')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

What I want to achieve, is when I have 3 objects, and add any combination of them to the synonymous field, I want all of them to be connected.

```
# Create synonymous words
bunny = Word.objects.create(name='bunny')
hare = Word.objects.create(name='hare')
rabbit = Word.objects.create(name='rabbit')
# Set synonymous words to rabbit
rabbit.synonymous.set([bunny, hare])
```

Now when I get the synonymous objects of rabbit, it has what I want:

```
(Pdb) rabbit.synonymous.all()
<QuerySet [<Word: bunny>, <Word: hare>]>
```

But when I take the synonymous objects of bunny and hare, they only return rabbit.

```
(Pdb) bunny.synonymous.all()
<QuerySet [<Word: rabbit>]>
(Pdb) hare.synonymous.all()
<QuerySet [<Word: rabbit>]>
```

What I'd like to achieve, is all the synonymous objects, to be "symmetrical". Now, the m2m field is already symmetrical, but it only stops at one object, not all given synonymous objects.

So, the ideal result would be this:

```
# Create synonymous words
bunny = Word.objects.create(name='bunny')
hare = Word.objects.create(name='hare')
rabbit = Word.objects.create(name='rabbit')
# Set synonymous ON ONE WORD
rabbit.synonymous.set([bunny, hare])

# And now ALL the objects, which have at least ONE related synonym, would automatically be assigned to the other words as well
(Pdb) rabbit.synonymous.all()
<QuerySet [<Word: bunny>, <Word: hare>]>
(Pdb) hare.synonymous.all()
<QuerySet [<Word: bunny>, <Word: rabbit>]>
(Pdb) bunny.synonymous.all()
<QuerySet [<Word: rabbit>, <Word: hare>]>
```

I hope that was clear.

I'm wondering whats the cleanest way to achieve this? Perhaps there is some way to do it through the ORM, but I'm having doubts.

Am I best off just writing a signal that manages those relationships manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to create all symmetric relationships at once like that because:

- `rabbit.synonymous` is a descriptor (`ManyToManyDescriptor`) that actually returns the `ManyRelatedManager` on instance attribute access
- as the to-many manager attaches the relations to a single object, the `ManyRelatedManager` does not have any such method as expected as it is an attribute of a single instance (`rabbit` in this case) unlike the forward model manager (e.g. `models.Manager` accessed as `objects`) which is applicable on a collection of rows/instances

---

To get what you want, you can create a helper function to create all inter-relations between the passed objects:

```
from itertools import combinations

def create_m2m_inter_relations(*objs): 
    if len(objs) < 2: 
        raise ValueError(
            'There must be at least two objects '
            'passed to create relationship.'
        ) 

    if len(objs) == 2: 
        objs[0].set([objs[1]]) 
        return 

    objs = set(objs) 
    relations_map = {
        next(iter(objs.difference(comb))): comb
        for comb in combinations(objs, len(objs) - 1)
    }  
    for instance, relations in relations_map.items():
        instance.synonymous.set(relations)
```

**Caveats:**

- As Django M2M relations are symmetric, the above duplicates the same `set` operations for a relationship already established in an earlier iteration of the loop. Removing the duplicate `set` operations is left as an exercise for the reader.
- As you're creating relations with all the objects have the same name for `ManyToManyDescriptor` -- `synonymous`, it is hardcoded in the function and will work fine in this case. But if you want a more generic solution take this into account and do modifications accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to achieve this is through the code below:

```
for word in synonymous:
    word.synonymous.set(synonymous.exclude(pk=word.pk))
```

**Edit**

The best spot to place this code is within your `views.py`. If you're using Django Admin, you should use [save_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related).

Answer (score 0):

As [heemayl mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59103840/synonymous-many-to-many-model-relationship-in-django/59114547#59114547), there is no way to do it directly through the ORM.

So I ended up making 2 functions, one for getting/finding all the synonymous relationships, and the other for setting/syncing them

For getting/finding:

```
def get_all_synonymous_words(word):
    # Start with the word's own synonymous words, and their synonymous words
    found_syn_ids = set(word.synonymous.values_list('id', flat=True)) | set(word.synonymous.values_list('synonymous', flat=True))

    while found_syn_ids:
        words = Word.objects.filter(id__in=found_syn_ids)
        batch_syn_ids = set(words.values_list('synonymous', flat=True))

        # If the batch syn ids are equal to last batch ids, all relationships found
        if batch_syn_ids == found_syn_ids:
            return batch_syn_ids

        found_syn_ids = batch_syn_ids
```

For setting/syncing:

```
def set_all_synonymous_words(word):
    syn_ids = get_all_synonymous_words(word)
    if syn_ids:
        syn_qs = Word.objects.filter(id__in=syn_ids)
        for word in syn_qs:
            # Exclude current word to not self reference
            excluded_qs = syn_qs.exclude(id=word.id)
            if not set(word.synonymous.exclude(id=word.id)) == excluded_qs:
                word.synonymous.set(excluded_qs)
```

This way, when you update/create words, you can find all the combinations, and update them, without having a list of the synonyms pre-defined.

As I use the django-rest-framework, I call it out in views, by overriding the perform_update/perform_create methods:

```
    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

        # Get the updated word, and sync the synonymous words to be all symmetrical
        set_all_synonymous_words(Word.objects.get(id=serializer.data['id']))


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

        # Get the updated word, and sync the synonymous words to be all symmetrical
        set_all_synonymous_words(Word.objects.get(id=serializer.data['id']))
```

Or you can call it out manually:

```
    # Create synonymous words
    bunny = Word.objects.create(name='bunny')
    hare = Word.objects.create(name='hare')
    rabbit = Word.objects.create(name='rabbit')
    # Set synonymous
    rabbit.synonymous.set([bunny, hare])
    # Sync synonymous
    set_all_synonymous_words(bunny)
```